# integrate opengl context into java swing

Tags: java, c++, swing, opengl

I am planning to develop a Java GUI application with some 3D function, I can develop 3D part functionality with opengl and C++. but I am not lucky enough to google any document for java to provide opengl window context for C++ code.

Majority of the material suggests JOGL which provides much more straightforward but that means I have to re-develop the same logic to be developed again.

my question is, is there anyway I can use Java swing to provide opengl context so that opengl code wrote in C++ can be used in Java?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious sorry for this mistake, my question is, is there anyway I can use Java swing to provide opengl context so that opengl code wrote in C++ can be used in Java?

Comment: What about porting everything to jogl? How much code are we talking about?

Comment: @elect I am not sure, since some opengl functionalities rely on third party,  using JOGL means I have to re-implement them all. so I prefer Swing provide a window for OpenGL renderings.

Comment: Can you list these third parties? Are they many?

Comment: u must use [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) to make a library written in another language accessible to Java code, or simply use jogl

Comment: @elect I used CGAL for Constructive solid geometry, that means I have to rewrite the logic of meshes invocations and file formate again in Java. that is why I prefer Java with C++ way

Comment: [JCSG](https://github.com/miho/JCSG) may be interesting for you

Answer (score 1):

Seems like JOGL (Java™ Binding for the OpenGL® API) is the only option. Also, you may have performance penalties if you are trying to mix Swing and OpenGL.